# Unble to use image which is store in django database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i create a model name profile with the help of signal so ever time a user get created it automatically create a profile with that usename in db all i want to fetch the image which i used as default in model like we fetch username with this {{ user.username }}
here is my code
my model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User ,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics/', default='default.png',)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,editable=False)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

my html

```
<img class="profile-pic nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="max-width: 45px; max-height:45px; border-radius: 50%;" src="{{ user.Profile.profile_pic.url|escape }}" >
```

my views.py
@login_required

```
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Profileform(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('accounts:home')
    else:
        form = Profileform()
    return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', {'form': form})

please help
```

Comment: I don't see your view, and how did you come about user.Profile? That doesn't seem right. If anything, it should be user.profile_pic.url, after getting the specific user in your view of cos.

Comment: i tried src="{{ user.profile_pic.url }}" but it didn't work and i did not created view for that model

Comment: You need to create a view that specifically gets the user you want, then renders it to the HTML in question. Then you can get whatever you want from the user, be it the image or any other field in the Profile model. E.g user.profile.profile_pic.url, note the lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

As pre [Sajere Kells](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10218761/sajere-kells) comment, use lowercase of model name when using reverse lookups.